# Python reading audio from sound card

Tags: python, audio, soundcard

I have a project. What I want to do is that I want  to read audio data from soundcard  without saving it but the main important thing is that the audio data that the python is reading I want to check if some certain audio is played

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Before the answer:**
In SO you should post your initial ideas, and say what you tried.
And then the answers can be more relevant and informative.

**About your question:** you can use [pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/)
It is:

`PyAudio provides Python bindings for PortAudio, the cross-platform audio I/O library. With PyAudio, you can easily use Python to play and record audio on a variety of platforms.`

There are multiple code examples for it, you can Google it.